# Django - Model with preset field (custom field)

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have a field that I usualy set as

```
rate = models.DecimalField(
  max_digits=2,
  decimal_places=1,
  choices=MY_CHOICES,
)
```

Is there a way I could define it like

```
rate = mymodels.MyRateField()
```

?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use inheritance:

```
class RateField(models.DecimalField):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        kwargs.update(dict(max_digits=2, decimal_places=1, choices=MY_CHOICES))
        super(RateField, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

rate = RateField()
```

Comment: Thank you. Sorry to ask this obvious question.

Comment: Some people learn by asking questions! Also, creating custom fields is more of an advanced topic that you might not just run across when first starting out.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you could subclass `DecimalField` and override its `__init__`.